# Importing external .js file to nuxt.config.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to import config.js which includes project's API keys. But It returns undefined.

```
//config.js
var config = {
   fbAPI: "key"
}
```

-

```
//nuxt.config.js

const cfg = require('./config')
env: {
   fbAPI: cfg.apiKey
}
```

Is this problem about run-time or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `modules.export` at the end of `config.js`. The file should look following:

```
var config = {
   fbAPI: "key"
}

module.exports = config;
```